# Spawn a child proccess, and send commands to its STDIN from Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spawn

Actually am totally confused how to ask this doubt due to lack of knowledge about this topic.

What i need is, i want to create an image file (`png`).For that run an executable file in ubuntu (The file functions same as `imagemagick and works successfully in`node.js`)`and write text and output png into location `/local/bin/img.png`

Following process.Here run the image tool  `sampleexe`

```
   writeme = IO.popen("~/local/bin/sampleexe", "w")
```

Using below code to write in to image file and save it into one location.But I don't know following code is correct or not.

```
writeme = IO.popen("~/local/bin/sampleexe", "w")
writeme.puts "hello" # program will get hello\n on STDIN

writeme.puts "font=Chewy" 
writeme.puts "font_size=40"
writeme.puts "message=Hello,world"

writeme.puts <<-HTML
      <h2>ffffffffffffffffffffffffff</h2>
       width=900  
    HTML

writeme.puts 'output=./local/bin/img.png'

writeme.close
```

I got `img.png` file in the mentioned path.but it could not open.Please help.

Using node.js the tool `sampleexe` succesfully write inputs (textmessage,textboxes,) and output these inputs to png file i have to implement same using ruby also

`node.js` working code

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var imgGen = spawn('sampleexe');

imgGen.stderr.on('data', function(chunk) {
  console.error(chunk.toString());
});
 imgGen.stdin.write('width=900\n');
          imgGen.stdin.write('height=400\n');


          imgGen.stdin.write('textboxes=<textboxes>'
                + '<textbox><rect>0,0,500,250</rect><color>0,0,0</color><font>Helvetica</font><align>Center</align><message>' + url.query.msg1 + '</message></textbox>'
                + '<textbox><rect>0,250,300,100</rect><color>200,0,0</color><font>Helvetica</font><align>Right</align><message>' + url.query.msg2 + '</message></textbox>'
                + '<textbox><rect>600,50,200,300</rect><color>255,153,10</color><font>Helvetica</font><justify>true</justify><message>'+url.query.msg3 + '</message></textbox>'
                + '</textboxes>\n');
          imgGen.stdin.write('output=/tmp/img.png\n');
```

Comment: Could you show how `sampleexe` is used normally, outside of Ruby? E.g. how would you invoke and use this in bash? Knowing that will help choose best approach in Ruby

Comment: Just add 4th variable on the left side to set spawned thread instance. Check its status, also content of stdout and stderr IO objects if something didn't go wrong. Also don't forget to flush/close IO objects to force output to be written. Last question, do you really intend to write to stdin(standard input) instead of stdout ?

Comment: @David Unric: AFAICS, the OP is trying to send params to the child process by writing to *its* stdin via the `stdin` variable. It is not possible to write to `stdout` (as in the variable set in the question's code) from the parent process, it is read-only on that side. Without seeing how the image-writer is supposed to work, it is  hard to tell how far the OP's attempts are from a working solution.